# Syntax error in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view

I am using `image_tag` in rails views and here is my code:

```
<%= image_tag "01-landing_page.png" class: "img-responsive" %>
```

But when I am running it. I am getting :

```
app/views/home/index.html.erb:252: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
app/views/home/index.html.erb:288: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting ')'
```

What I am doing wrong here. I followed a lot of SO post but all of them are mentioning to write the class in a same manner.

Answer (score 1):

You have a little syntax error in your code. There should be a comma after the image as follow:

```
<%= image_tag "01-landing_page.png", class: "img-responsive" %>
```

I'm sure that putting that comma there will solve the problem.